# Scrapy pipeline performance

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm currently using Scrapy for a personal project but struggling on a performance aspect.

When I don't use the pipeline, my 4 simulatenous crawlers can crawl 600 pages in 30 seconds.

I've implemented a custom pipeline to process the scripts in each page and compare them to a list of 5000 url to check if the url exists in the script code.

**The issue is that this makes my crawl run for 110 seconds instead of 30 seconds when I don't use the pipeline.**

I'm wondering how I can optimize my code given that for each page, I check each of my link through all my scripts.

Below is how it looks:

Can we run multithreading to go faster on the loops?

**Parse function within the spider class:**

```
    def parse(self, response):

    print('### SCANNED: %s', (response.request.url))

    if len(response.css('script').getall()) > 0:

        yield {
            'domain': response.meta['domain'],
            'scripts': response.css('script').getall()
        }
```

**Process item function within the pipeline**

```
    def process_item(self, item, spider):

    domain = item['domain']
    scripts = item['scripts']

      for script in scripts: # There are about 15 scripts per item

        for script_group in self.script_groups: # There are about 5000 script_groups

            # Check all urls in script_group to see if script_group is being used

            for url in script_group['urls']: # There are about 2 urls per script_group
                # If at least one url found then script_group is being used

                if url in script:

                    print("url found, script_group is being used")
                    break

    return item
```

Comment: Do you use dictionaries for your `script_group`?

Comment: Yes. Here is the example of a script_group

{
   "script_group_id":464,
    "urls" : (google-analytics.com, urchin.com)
}

Comment: Try to use dictionary for your `urls`

Answer (score 1):

Try avoiding so many for loops.

For example:

1. Create a regular expression object in the pipeline `__init__` method from `self.script_groups`:

```py
    self.url_re = re.compile(
        '(?:{})'.format(
            '|'.join(
                re.escape(url)
                for url in group['urls']
                for group in self.script_groups
            )
        )
    )
```

2. Use it:

```py
    for script in scripts:
        if self.url_re.search(script):
            print("url found, script_group is being used")
            break
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a great idea.
The only small issue I have is that I'm losing the reference of the script_group the url was found in